# Comparison between various types of cell complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

There are the following (and more) types of geometric cell complexes:

- 1) The geometric realization of a simplicial set
- 2) CW-complexes
- 3) The geometric realization of an abstract simplicial complex
- 4) A geometric simplicial complex

What are the differences? Which of these classes of spaces include each other, and what are examples which demonstrate that these classes don't coincide? Of course I am only interested in the (not weak!) homotopy types.

I hope that 3),4) are the same, and that these are a special case of 1), which is also a special case of 2).

If some inclusion doesn't hold for trivial reasons (say not every CW-complex is the geometric realization of a simplicial complex), what assumptions should we add to get a better comparision (for example what about regular CW-complexes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some partial thoughts:

- There are CW complexes that are not the geometric realization of a simplicial set. [See this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34674/example-of-a-cw-complex-not-homeomorphic-to-the-realization-of-a-simplicial-set)
- By a result of Milnor the geometric realization of a locally finite simplicial set is a CW complex (Milnor, "The geometric realization of a semi-simplicial complex").
- I'm not so sure on 3 and 4 but on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23713/simplicial-complexes-vs-geometric-realization-of-abstract-simplicial-complexes/23807#23807) answer it looks like Allen Hatcher is suggest they are equivalent